# Skin preview image addition in DNN 7.0 - "Image not available" in Site wizard

Tags: dotnetnuke, admin, packaging

I have created a skin using dnn 7.0. I packaged it and installed it. Its working fine but when i open Admin ->  Site Wizard in control bar I see my skins file showing "Image not available". But i have took my skin screenshots and placed in skin folder. But how do i reference them to DNN manifest file.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help you which gives answer to your question perfectly.
http://nithinchandrasr.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-create-thumbnail-preview-images.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/213634) for more information.